# how to extract text from pdf using ghostscript in php

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript

I am trying to extract text from pdf using following command but it isn't working and returning null.

```
$text = shell_exec(gs -q -sDEVICE=txtwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dFirstPage='.(int)$page_number.' -dLastPage='.(int)($page_number+1).' -sOutputFile=textfilename.txt exemple.pdf');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a string as a parameter there and you need to escape values before passing them to the command. Finally, you need to specify an output file, in this case you want the data to go to `STDOUT` for access by PHP.

```
$first_page = escapeshellarg((int)$page_number);
$last_page = escapeshellarg($page_number + 1);
$text = shell_exec("gs -q -sDEVICE=txtwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dFirstPage=$first_page -dLastPage=$last_page -sOutputFile=%stdout exemple.pdf");
```

Comment: can you tell me how can I read PDF? or tell me the way to extract text from pdf?

Comment: No. I imagine there are resources out there to answer that question.

Comment: The command line in the original post is reading a PDF (ememple.pdf) in and sending it to the txtwrite device, which extracts text, and writes the result to 'OutputFile'. So its doing what the OP wanted. The problem is mikem32 has accidentally collapsed the OutputFile switch and the input filename into a single argument to -sOutputFile. You need "-sOutputFile=textfilename.txt exemple.pdf"

Comment: Thanks @KenS. Based [on documentation](https://ghostscript.com/doc/7.07/Use.htm#File_output) I've used the filename `%stdout` which should output the text directly for use by PHP.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am getting Output but there is a problem. I am getting text in chinese :(

Comment: Most likely you are using an old version of Ghostscript, there was a temporary bug in one version (I think 9.19) which reversed the byte order of the UTF-16 output. **However** you should be aware that many PDF files will **not** produce the text you expect for a number of reasons. The only reliable form is a PDF where all the fonts have ToUnicode CMaps (which are optional). PostScript or PCL input (shoud you try those) can't have ToUnicode CMaps and so are even less reliable.